# How can you configure the uPnP server on windows home server?

Tags: windows-home-server, upnp, dlna

I'm currently helping my parents with their home network set up while I'm home.  I have a Synology NAS device which supports a uPnP server.  I have a few MPEG-4 movies stored on the box, and simply enabling the uPnP server on the NAS streamed the video to some devices they have, including their Xbox 360 and Samsung television.

They have a windows home server (HP MediaSmart.)  I put one of the movies in the "Videos" folder of the device, and enabled sharing.  It shows up on the television, but when played it produces an "unsupported file type" error.  I have all of the transcoding settings disabled on the Synology device, so it should be streaming the same file.  Is there some additional configuration I need to perform on the home server unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually ended up buying an X-Box 360 for the Kinect sensor, and that seems to play the videos fine off of the home server.  There must have been some kind of encoding problem or something that the TV wasn't capable of handling.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a uPnP problem to me, as you are able to see the file on the TV. However, you should go into the Home Server console, click on the Settings link in the upper right hand corner, go to the Media Sharing tab and confirm they are all turned on.

HP MediaSmart also use a media streaming solution (TwonkyMedia). That may be causing some conflicts. Its settings are on a different tab on the Settings dialog.